# How to unit test file manager class?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, nunit

I wrote a simple class to manage business objects.

```
class Manager
{ 
 string[] GetNames();
 BObject GetObject(string name);
 void Saveobject(BObject obj);
}
```

It serializes /deserializes the objects as files on a local disk. I wrote Unit tests for the class and run them. That was fine so far. The problem happens when my test were run on build server because of file access permission I was not allowed to write files on the server. It's obvious I cannot test that way.

I think how to unit test this. One approach I can see is to extract an interface and creat a mock object for testing. But I want to test the class itself. How can I do it?

Comment: Ofc it makes sense to test how the system works in real conditions, but that just isn't called unit-testing - it's integration testing, or system testing. And these must have some special environment prepared.

Comment: @driushkin yes. you're right. But I'm curious to muddle through it with Unit tests ))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class presumably calls file system operations `File.OpenRead()`, `File.OpenWrite()` etc. (I assume that this is C# due to the camel casing.) Then, you could create an interface for those operations, e.g.:

```
public interface IFileSystem {
    StreamReader OpenRead(string fileName);
    StreamWriter OpenWrite(string fileName);
}
```

and make the constructor of `Manager` take an instance of `IFileSystem`. Then, write a (non-mock) class that implements `IFileSystem` by calling the actual `File.OpenRead()` and `File.OpenWrite()` methods and use this one in the production code. In the tests, you use a mock framework, as mentioned by @Digger (my personal preference is [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/), but I haven't tried Rhino Mocks, so I have nothing negative to say about it) to mock out `IFileSystem` and use the mock to verify that the methods were called with the correct serialized data.

EDIT: Per request, an example in NUnit with Moq (I don't have an IDE here, so it's untested; feel free to correct it):

```
[Test]
public void BObjectShouldBeSerializedToFile() {
    var fileSystemMock = new Mock<IFileSystem>();
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    fileSystemMock.Setup(f => f.OpenWrite("theFileNameYouExpect.txt")).Returns(new StreamWriter(stream)).Verifiable();
    var manager = new Manager(fileSystemMock.Object);

    manager.SaveObject(new BObject(...));

    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    Assert.That(...); // Perform asserts on the stream contents here
    fileSystemMock.Verify(); // Not really necessary, but verify that `OpenWrite` was called
}
```

Comment: you mean to verify StreamReader's content while unit-testing? Does Moq(Rhino) can do it? Can you supply a simple example?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how much logic is contained in your class, in my opinion.

If there's some complicated logic inside your manager, it makes sense to abstract your file operations as per Aasmund's suggestion so that the logic can be tested independently of the file system.  I do this when something is finicky enough to warrant the extra dependencies.

On the other hand, if there's very little logic other than calling into your serialization/deserialization code, then it's often acceptable to skip the unit tests and run integration tests that test the full cycle (create a `BObject` in memory, persist it via calling `SaveObject`, read it back out using `GetObject`, ensure that it is equal/equivalent to the one you persisted in the first place).

If your build environment can't run integration tests, then I'd look into setting it up so that it's possible.